# SQL Inner Join Order Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

Im trying to order my selection from the db and the results is wrong. Im trying to get ASC ordering. Here is my selection code:

```
SELECT b.product_id, a.file_destination
FROM images AS a 
INNER JOIN product_images AS b
WHERE a.image_id = b.image_id
GROUP BY b.product_id
ORDER BY b.order ASC
```

With this Im getting some kind of random order. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `ON` instead of `WHERE` for the join condition to write correct SQL.

Comment: I try that too, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: what is the type of "b.order" ? does this column contains NULL values?

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid, will return an unpredictable result in older MySQL versions, will raise an error in new versions (unless in compatibility mode.) The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: What do you want to achieve actually? You group by product, so you have one row per product and then you order by "order", but a product may have several different "order". Are you trying to get the first image per product? This cannot be done thus, because aggregation takes place before ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1):

`b.order` is not in the `GROUP BY`.  Nor does it have an aggregation function.  Hence, it should not be allowed.  A properly formed query would look more like this:

```
SELECT pi.product_id, MAX(i.file_destination)
FROM images i INNER JOIN
     product_images pi
WHERE i.image_id = pi.image_id 
GROUP BY pi.product_id
ORDER BY MAX(pi.order) ASC;
```

Comment: I think `order` also should be in backticks, or with the table notation it is alright?

Comment: @Strawberry . . . It returns the maximum value of the column for each product.

Comment: According to ANSI SQL: when GROUP BY, only select list items are allowed in the ORDER BY clause. Try removing the ORDER BY and see what happens.

Comment: @jarlh . . . You generally can include any expression with aggregation functions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found the solution. The final code is:

```
SELECT b.product_id, a.file_destination
FROM images AS a 
INNER JOIN product_images AS b
ON a.image_id = b.image_id
WHERE b.order = 1
GROUP BY b.product_id
```